# How do I get basic information through the Health App

Tags: android

I want to obtain the movement data such as the number of steps, heartbeat and so on from the watch running Wear Os through Android.
Or I want to get my health data from the health app on Android

Can someone tell me what documentation to look at, or is there a solution